# Magit: enable `toggle-truncate-line` in diff-mode

Tags: magit

I'm working with tex files that have usually long lines of text. I enabled in magit the fine coloration of errors by using:

```
(setq-default magit-diff-refine-hunk 'all)
```

and now I'd like to disable the `truncate-line` function. How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: just add a hook to magit-diff-mode and call `toggle-truncate-line`. That should do it

Comment: Why would you want to *toggle* it automatically?  Surely you either want it "on" or "off"; rather than "the opposite of whatever it is at the moment" ?

Comment: And your text is confusing. Do you want this for `diff-mode` (as per your subject), or `magit-diff-mode` (which I would expect from the rest of your text) ?

Comment: @phils Yes indeed, I sayed toggle just because by default it's always off. And I want it for the `diff-mode` of magit, which appears to be `magit-diff-mode`, I though that magit was using an already existing mode to display this, and I didn't want to interfer with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that this is what you want:

```el
(defun my-truncate-lines ()
  (setq truncate-lines t))

(add-hook 'magit-diff-mode-hook 'my-truncate-lines)
```

Comment: indeed I wasn't clear (just updated), by default it truncates the line and I want not to truncate them. So I want "nil" instead of "t", but else it's perfect, I did not known about the `magit-diff-mode-hook` thing. Thanks.

Comment: All modes have a mode hook, which is always the name of the mode function with a `-hook` suffix.  (In the case of minor modes, the hook is called when the mode is enable *or* disabled, so you often want to test the mode variable so that you can act in accordance with its current state.)

Comment: This probably goes without saying, but as you *actually* wanted a value of `nil` the name `my-truncate-lines` would be somewhat misleading, so you probably want to rename that to something more appropriate.

Comment: Yes thanks, that's what I did. But actually, in my mind truncate looks like "I cut the line and put the following below", while in fact it's "hide the last part of the line". Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a little tip: if you just use `magit-mode-hook` instead of `magit-diff-mode-hook` in the solution already answered can also preserve diff lines under "Staged changes" and "Unstaged changes" on the `magit-status` (magit home) as well as `magit-diff` buffer.

```lisp
;; just summarized the above teachers' comments.
(defun untruncate-lines ()
  (setq truncate-lines nil)) 

(add-hook 'magit-mode-hook 'untruncate-lines) ;; also works for `magit-diff-mode`
```